# angular is not defined in meteor-velocity jasmine tests

Tags: jasmine, angular-meteor, meteor-velocity

I have meteor app and want to test some angular controllers. So in `package.js`

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  var CLIENT = 'client',
    SERVER = 'server',
    BOTH = [CLIENT, SERVER];

  api.use('sanjo:jasmine@0.13.6', BOTH);
  api.use('angular', BOTH);
  api.use('angular:angular-mocks@1.4.4', BOTH);
  api.use('mdg:camera@1.1.5', BOTH);

  api.use('underscore', BOTH);
  api.use('session', BOTH);
  api.use('mongo', BOTH);
  api.use('tracker', BOTH);
  api.addFiles([
    'tests/jasmine/server/integration/permission.js'
  ], BOTH);
});
```

and in test file

```
describe('пермишны', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('myapp.myModule');
    angular.mock.inject(function (_$meteorUtils_, _$rootScope_) {
      $meteorUtils = _$meteorUtils_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      // Creates a new child scope.
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
  });
  ...
});
```

When i run `VELOCITY_TEST_PACKAGES=1 meteor test-packages --driver-package velocity:html-reporter ./` it gives me an error `ReferenceError: angular is not defined` (in browser). So the question is how to use angular and other modules defined in `onTest` function in this test?

`packages` file:

```
angularui:angular-ui-router
angular:angular-material
less
ncuillery:angular-breadcrumb
accounts-ui
accounts-base
service-configuration
accounts-google
meteorhacks:ssr
meteorhacks:npm

momentjs:moment


npm-container
liyu:sprintfjs
standard-minifiers
meteor-base
mobile-experience
mongo
blaze-html-templates
session
jquery
tracker
logging
reload
random
ejson
spacebars
check
angular
velocity:html-reporter
velocity:console-reporter
sanjo:jasmine
angular:angular-mocks
```

Comment: Hey buddie, how did you fixed this?

Comment: Hey @Vercryger. This issue is still active, have found no solutions :(